# To list all the available fields in a huge Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

What is way to export a list of each table and its fields from a pivot table?

I have a large pivot table, reading external source, with dozens of tables and more than a hundred fields.

There are many similar fields and I don't know which one is the best to choose from, so I want an overview of all the available fields.

What is the way to export a list of all of the fields so that I can build a little dictionary.

Thank you.

Comment: You can check out to see if this helps - [excel-vba-pivotTable-fields-list](https://www.contextures.com/excel-vba-pivot-table-field-list.html)

Comment: Refer to this similar case: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/50010-listing-pivottable-field-list-fields/

Comment: @Lee is spot on. Answer #8 seems like it's the one for you, since you say "dozens of tables", it's likely you are actually connected to a cube and need to list the pivot table's cube fields.